# Cut text from "the_content" function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using "the_content" function but the content is too long and i want to cut it without creating functions, filters etc.. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try to use the_excerpt function instead of the_content, This url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nS-3kC9VC4A may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  quicktag `<!--more-->` in posts to tell [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) function where to cut the text.

Another way would be to use [the_excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) function instead of `the_content`. One reason to use `the_excerpt` is that you don't need to bother with `<!--more-->` quicktags.